# How can I recreate a material from blender in Unreal engine

Tags: shaders, unreal-4, blender, materials, color

I'm new to unreal and I am having trouble finding a way to reproduce the materials for a mesh in blender in unreal. It's a simple material but I can't find a way to reproduce the color ramp specifically. Is there any unreal alternative or just some way i can reproduce it. the way I'm using the color ramp is so that light is so the material is affected by the light.

Comment: Try not to use external links, best way is to describe what you mean by tools that the website provides. You can probably use a GIF - https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/404/how-to-post-gifs-on-this-site or just a couple of images. What have you already tried? Seems like you need a shader for a material in UE that works the same way as it does in Blender, is that right?

Comment: Thank you for the tip, and yes that's right

Comment: You could post images of the shader in Blender, like nodes and examples of the final result. Maybe, someone will know how to reproduce that effect in shader code or other type of system that UE uses for shaders.